# how would I add index to all returned results when using pagination

Tags: laravel

I want to give index to each result from a query, something like this

page 1

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

page 2

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

page 3

```
etc
```

How would I do that? I can't use the id from the table, and I can't use $loop->iteration to print out a the index for each result, since loop->iteration would reset for each page load if I am correct?

How would I give index to all returned results and have it work accors all the pages

Comment: By index do you mean `(Page num x Items per page) + loop->iteration` ?

Comment: yes that was it :) actually with little change (page num-1 x items per page) + loop->iteration

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$loop->iteration`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable) and [pagination instance methods:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

```
($results->currentPage() - 1) * $results->perPage() + $loop->iteration
```

Comment: ok If I do this

´{{ ($listings->currentPage()) * $listings->perPage() + $loop->index }}´

it starts with 2, 3, 4 and so on. If I do this

´{{ ($listings->currentPage() - 1) * $listings->perPage() + $loop->index }} ´
it starts with 0,1,2 and so on. How to start with 1?

Comment: ok this does the trick:


{{ ($listings->currentPage() - 1) * $listings->perPage() + $loop->iteration }}

Comment: Yeah, I've just updated the answer with the same method )